# How to skip nodes of starting in linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to work on pointers.
I am under a situation that i want to traverse the linked list after the second node(from third node).

I have the basic idea to traversing the linked list is:

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
 temp=temp->next;
}
```

So what i want is this linked list must start from third position. Could anyone please help me in preparing logic for that? **I am not interested in any using any in-built functions**.
I will use this logic in other application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list is `temp` then `temp` is also the first element.

Then `temp->next` will be second element, and `temp->next->next` will be the third.

So if you write

```
temp = temp->next->next;
```

`temp` will be pointing to the third element and you can start your traverse from there.

Answer (score 2):

```
Node *nth(Node *head, int nth){//nth : 0 origin
    while(nth && head){
        --nth;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return head;
}
...
Node *third = nth(head, 2);
```